# Installing Dual Boot Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron i5565-5850GRY with AMD FX-9800P

Tags: dual-boot, amd-processor

My laptop had pre-installed Windows 10. I tried to install Ubuntu 16.043 as dual boot. The installation seems to be having an issue. During installation, while installing Ubuntu from the bootable USB, I have to pass "amd_iommu=off" as a kernel parameter, otherwise the installation goes into an infinite loop of showing the error "AMD-Vi completion loop timed out". Due to passing the kernel parameter, the installation has worked, but I have to pass it again every time I try to boot to Ubuntu. I have read that this kernel parameter is used to turn off virtualization. Is there any way to permanently turn off virtualization? I could not find it in the Boot menu. Is there any way to install and run Ubuntu without turning off virtualiation?

Specs:
Processor: AMD FX-9800P
RAM: 16 GB
HDD: 1 TB
Graphics card: Radeon R7 M445 Graphics
Also, could the issue be something other than virtualization?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can permanently set the `amd_iommu=off` kernel parameter by referring to https://askubuntu.com/a/19487